# How to Display Empty Fields in views

Tags: views

How do I Display empty fields in Views? Empty_Fields module does not work for me as there needs to be a custom text for it to display.

I want to display all labels even if the fields are empty. How do i achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Views field settings add `&nbsp;` to `No results behavior`. Your View  will then display a space and a field label if the field is empty.

[image]

---

If you're using Unformatted list format for your View block, then in `Format -> Fields -> Settings` make sure that `Hide empty fields` checkbox is unchecked. See screenshots below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the tip oksana-c. I tried that, it still doesn't display the fields. Anything else that I can try?

Comment: @GirishCholayill You can try adding `<br/>` instead of `&nbsp;`. If that doesn't work - you'll need to provide more info on how your View fields are configured.

Comment: tried that, still no go. Basically what I am trying to achieve is, I have a custom Module of contacts with many fields. I am creating a custom node view using either Panels or Views (Created view blocks of certain specific fields) to get a custom look. All fields in the custom Contact module don't have values. Some of them need to be input by the user when updating. A user may not know this field exists unless and until they try to edit the Contact Node. I want to display these empty fields for the user to see. While using either Panels or Views, these fields remain hidden.

Comment: @GirishCholayill see updates above.

Comment: Yes, it is in Unformatted list and the Hide Empty Fields is also unchecked.

Comment: @GirishCholayill are you rewriting the output of your fields with custom text?

Comment: I tried putting in only the HTML tags you directed me to. I haven't tried putting in any custom Text in it. I, actually, do not want to input any custom text for empty fields. If done it looks very messy. Is there any work around for this?

Comment: @GirishCholayill, you misunderstood me. I asked if you are using `Rewrite results` setting for your fields. You wouldn't want to add any text to `No Result Behavior` except for a space character or line break. I can't help you any further. What I said above should work. You must have configured something in a weird way, but I can't troubleshoot it with the information you provided.

Comment: I am not using any rewrite results. Its a pretty straight forward basic set up. I have selected the content type that I want to displayed and selected the fields for the same.